# Updating the Key of Object type in a Dictionary

Tags: c#

I'm very new to C# and using a dictionary.
I would like to edit the Key of a dictionary where the 
Key is an object of type Group. Group contains one public property GroupName
GroupName should be changed to the new string value. We are required to use objects and not strings as our keys. I tried the following:

```
***************************SEPERATE COLLECTION CLASS************************
{

    public class GroupKeysDictionary : Dictionary<Group, List<Key>> { }
}
*************************************************************************


private static GroupKeysDictionary _groupKeys = new GroupKeysDictionary();


public static class DataAccessMgr {    
    (Group g contains the original g.
    GroupName and k.GroupName is the new group name)    
    public static void EditGroup(Group g, Group k) {
        if (_groupKeys.ContainsKey(g)) {
            _groupKeys(g) = k 
        }
    }
```

Do I have to remove the group and re-add it?
I don't want to lose the values in the List.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by all means, remove the key and then add it back.

The idea behind a dictionary is that the key should not change once it is in the dictionary. Do not mutate it. If the key is modified in a substantive* way, it invalidates the hash code of the key and then the dictionary is effectively broken. If you want to reassociate the value to a different key, use the original key to get the value, remove the key, and then add the *new* key along with the value back to the dictionary.

What you might want to try is

```
if (_groupKeys.ContainsKey(g) && !_groupKeys.ContainsKey(k))
{
     var value = _groupKeys[g];
     _groupKeys.Remove(g);
     _groupKeys.Add(k, value);
}
```

---

*This answer assumes that your `Group` class has implemented its own `GetHashCode` and `Equals` methods that take into consideration your chosen primary property, `GroupName`. If your class does not provide such implementations, but rather relies upon default referential equality, then mutations of the key do not have the same harmful effect. But then your dictionary is also not quite as useful, as two distinct instances with the same `GroupName` could be used as keys, as they would not be referentially equal.

Comment: This sounds a lot like it belongs in an extension method.

Comment: @M.Babcock, sure, but it's overkill in regards to providing an answer (although someone could put it in an extension method if they like, perhaps with the signature `public static bool ReplaceKey<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey originalKey, TKey newKey)` where the method returns true/false if the key can be swapped), but I'm not presently of the mind to advocate extension methods all willy nilly.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram - I understand the question did not explicitly call for an extension method, my point was more that it *can* be generalized to work in a lot of situations. I know you know this (and I already have an extension method that does this) but for the OP and future readers they may not know it is possible.